# Can I convert an getElementbyId into a number to make a math operation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

This is a basic calculator project. I am having trouble to return the result, after any button is clicked it returns NaN. It has something to do with the input and how it translate into a number, but ".value" doesn't seem to be working

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <input type="text" id="num1-el">
    <input type="text" id="num2-el">

    <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <button onclick="subtract()">Subtract</button>
    <button onclick="divide()">Divide</button>
    <button onclick="multiply()">Multiply</button>

    <p id="sum-el">Sum: </p>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the JS file I can see that the variables get the elements but it can't make a math operations with them, even with parseInt and .value

JavScript file:

```
let num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1-el").value)
let num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2-el").value) 

let sum = document.getElementById("sum-el")

let operation

function add() {
    operation = num1 + num2;
    sum.textContent += operation + " | ";
}

function subtract() {
    operation = num1 - num2;
    sum.textContent += operation + " | ";
}

function divide() {
    operation = num1 / num2;
    sum.textContent += operation + " | ";  
}

function multiply() {
    operation = num1 * num2;
    sum.textContent += operation + " | ";
}
```

Can someone help with this please? Thank you!
ps: This is my first question in stack overflow and english is not my first language, so I apologize in advance for any basic mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the script runs, num1 and num2 get their values just one first time, and both would be undefined. Therefor when you click the buttons and trigger functions, all results would be `NaN`.
Try this way:

```
let num1, num2

function getNumbers() {
    num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1-el").value)
    num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2-el").value)
}

function add() {
    getNumbers();
    operation = num1 + num2;
    sum.textContent += operation + " | ";
}

/* other functions */
```